# Web Service + IIS = Error 404.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

In my machine I've been enabled the IIS with ASP.NET, see pic below:

[image]

When I go to http://localhost the default website open normally.

After that, I created a default WCF project in Visual Studio 2017 in .NET 4.5.

This WCF have an interface **ISercvice1.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}

[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

And a default SVC **Service1.svc**, see below:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

At the IIS I created a new site and referenced the folder inside inetpub folder:

[image]

But when I try to open the link (http://localhost:8765/Service1.svc) the error appears:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

I don't know what I can do to solve this error, can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run aspnet_regiis.exe -i command line.

Solution 2: Try enabling the below under .NET Framework.

[image]

Comment: I did, but it didn't work